# Dynamic mirror site (2 domains same content)

Tags: php, mirror, multiple-domains, smf-forum

There is my problem: I have a forum (creating with SMF engine), that is a dynamic website.

I want to make an other website (with an other domain), with exactly the same content, except some details (like the `<title>` content and the css sheets). But it has to work dynamically too: the two forum must be one, with the same content at the same time.

I'm a bit loss, and I'm not sure I'm aware of all tools maybe I have. Can I do that in a simple way (like a simple generated php script or something), or is it going to be more complicated?

Comment: Simplest way would be to put Site A in an `iframe` in Site B right?

Comment: If you want the data to be sync'd but to have different appearances just have them both connect to the same data source and style them separately however you want on each domain?

Comment: @Darren If I'm doing it, I can't make any change on it, is it ?

Comment: @RyanKempt I'm not sure this is possible with SMF ; btw, I will try to install the CMS twice with the same DB if I don't found a better solution. Thank you !

Comment: @Yojin It is possible. Ensure your database engine has remote connections enabled and site X is able to connect to MySQL Engine located on site Y, or vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up the same DNS and have the exact same content, then have 2 style sheets, and using PHP:

```
$domain = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];

if($domain == "domain1") {
    echo "stylesheet1";
}else{
    echo "stylesheet2";
}
```

And this should be the same for anything else you want different.